# WSL restart errors

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

After wsl restart in PowerShell I got errors:

```
PS C:\docker_test\mosquitto> wsl --shutdown
PS C:\docker_test\mosquitto> wsl
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.

<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:370: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:374: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return
```

Why I'm getting these errors and how to fix them?

Comment: This might help? https://superuser.com/questions/1691352/processing-fstab-with-mount-a-failed sorry it's pretty hard since there's not much to go on. Can you try see if there's anything related in MS Event Viewer?

Comment: Isn't something missing from the question? In your pasted output, it seems that `wsl --shutdown` completed successfully, it's just after that when you try to open you get an error. But what are you trying to do running just `wsl`, by me that shows up with the help list. Don't you need to specify what you're doing and/or the distro name?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423048/i-am-getting-error-on-windows-subsystem